# Issue in sharing folders with other users in azure file share

Tags: azure, file, share

I have created a file share by using azure file share and the drive is mounted in my windows 10 client . but when i am trying to add someone else i am getting an error " Make sure the pc is azure domain joined "

I need help is solving this . please share any article or steps to grant the permissions to other users in Ad to access these file shares in Azure

Regards
Abhay

Comment: By "add someone else" do you mean give someone else access or mount the drive on someone elses computer?

Comment: I mean to give access to other users to read the folders inside the share i have created .

Comment: Do the other users have azure AD accounts? In the same domain as your account?

Comment: yes other users are synced from on prem AD , it should be in the same way as we grant in on prem

Comment: just want to let you know this share in mounted on my machine windows 10 machine , which is joined to onprem ad

Answer (score 1):

To do this your PC must be a member of the Azure AD domain. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable

Comment: I have deployed a new windows 10 client added that client  to the azure domain ,  but still  i am getting the same error , I was tying to configure the IAM for the share so that it can be accessed by other users ,in the console i was getting an error then i have created it by cli.

Comment: net use R: \\abhaystore.file.core.windows.net\cloudshare "0TRHpY1b5*************************" /user:Azure\abhaystore

The command completed successfully

Comment: Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: I was able to get this through by adding ADDS in azure and then after that  was able to grant permissions to other users in share